# Проблема при выполнении кода ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пишет ошибку и не выполняеться можете помочь

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сначала поместить папку resoursec в scr, а потом поместить файл aplicationContext.xml в папку META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Select "File" -> "Project Structure".

Under "Project Settings" select "Project"

From there you can select the "Project SDK".

сдделал версию SDK выше и сработало.